# If $f:A \to B$ is a real function, and $y\in B, $ Is Rudin's definition of $f^{-1}(y)$ commonly accepted as convention or not?

Tags: functions, notation, convention

Let $f:A \to B\ $ be a function.

In Rudin's PMA, at the bottom of page 24 and top of page 25, he states:

> If $y \in B, f^{-1}(y)\ $ is the **set** of all $x \in A\ $ such that
> $f(x) = y.\ $

This notation could be confused with the **function** $f^{-1}:B \to A.$

Is Rudin's use of $f^{-1}(y)$ as a **set** still conventional today?

Comment: When $f^{-1}(y)$ is a singleton, then $f^{-1}$ is a function. This definition is stnadard for me. Sometiemes I prefer to write $f^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Comment: It's still very common at the university where I'm studying right now. Indeed, the correct notation would be $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, but if you have to work with the preimages of singletons a lot, then it's reasonable to drop the curly braces. However, in my opinion it should be stated explicitly, since it sure confused me a lot in the beginning.

Comment: @Tito Eliatron Obviously. I'm more interested in when $f$ is not injective

Comment: I know of no other widespread convention to denote the inverse image of an element/set. It is usually pretty clear whether it is that or if we're talking of the inverse function.

Comment: " It is usually pretty clear whether it is that or if we're talking of the inverse function". Definitionally yes. However, people like myself who found it lots of effort to learn all the notation and language about sets and functions: image, pre-image, range, domain, co-domain etc. Might see $f^{-1}$ and think, "ah, so this is about the inverse function", even though no such function exists. So to an untrained eye, it surely could be confusing. However, my question has been answered nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{x\in A : f(x) \in \{y\}\}$ or more generally for a subset $C\subseteq A$
$$
f^{-1}(C) = \{x\in A : f(x) \in C\}
$$
is pretty standard and known as the [preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image).

When it is clear by context $f^{-1}(y)$ would also work but i would always make sure it is clear [as it might lead to confusion with the inverse function $f^{-1}$ which not necessarily exists]

Comment: As DonAntonio said in the comments, surely the set $f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{x\in A : f(x) \in \{y\}\}$ is well-defined (even if $y$ is not in the image of $f$), regardless of the existence of the function $f^{-1}.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes i didn't mean it wouldn't be well defined but rather lead to misunderstanding. especially among people who don't have much experience with those things (like your comment after DonAntonio's stated; it often leads to confusion among people who just start learning the foundations)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a common (I dare say the most common) notation for the set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, when it is clear by context that $f^{-1}$ does not indicate a purported inverse map of $f$.